# Nature of relationship between atmospheric $\rm CO_2$ and temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, atmospheric-science, physical-chemistry, climate-science

So I had a simple thought:

Venus is ~400C with 95% CO2, and Earth is ~15C with 0% CO2..

Assuming linearity, this equates to 1C for 1% atmospheric CO2.

Why is the relationship assumed to be so much more hyperbolic? There is no feedback loop where a little more CO2 unlocks more CO2 trapped in rocks - save for a little decomposing methane..

Comment: I think your model is a bit too simple to be useful. Venus has a much higher atmospheric pressure, with virtually no water in its atmosphere (it also contains traces of sulfur dioxide, an anti-greenhouse gas). It receives a lot more solar radiation, it has less mass & lower surface gravity.

Comment: What would the result be if you linearized temperature with respect to the total vertical column of CO2 (per unit surface area)?

Comment: Infrared absorption is per Lambert-Beer exponentially proportional to partial pressure times path length (scale height).